# Has anyone else started having problems taking screenshots in Windows 8.1 recently?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro and have been unable to take screenshots the last week or so. (Pretty sure it started after the latest update) Is anyone else having the same problem?

I've tried searching for an answer, but can't seem to find anything to help or explain this. The screen does still flash black momentarily as though a screenshot is being taken, and it IS saving a file, but the thumbnails are coming up solid black, and when previewed, are coming up solid white.

Since posting, I've found I can still screen cap pressing PrintScreen only and pasting from clipboard, though I can still no longer automatically capture to Screenshots folder with Windows Key + PrintScreen.

Surely I'm not the only one this is happening to? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Just pressing Windows Key + PrintScreen. Tried other keyboard shortcuts already with same result. Never had any problems taking them before. Problem has only started recently.

Comment: Sounds like you have third-party software installed interfering with the shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to use screenshot tools in clean boot to see if the issue is on the tool, or it has conflicts with others.
Try the safe boot and clean boot to see if the issue still occurs.
(1) Log on as administrator
(2) `Win+R` and type `msconfig`
(3) We will get the window of `System Configuration`
(4) Select `General` tab
(5) Select `Selective startup`, then uncheck `Load startup items`
(5) Then select `Services` tab.
(6) Check `Hide all Microsoft services` checkbox.
(7) Click `Disable all`
(8) Select `Startup tab`, and click `Open Task Manager`.
(9) Make sure that `Startup` tab is selected.
(10) On the selected tab, right-click each startup program one-by-one to disable them.
(11) Close `Task Manager` when done and go back on `System Configuration` box, click `OK`.
(12) Then restart the machine.
(13) Try the tool again.

And run other software, until the screenshot tool does not work. Or if the issue is on the tool, try to reinstall the tool.

Comment: Thank you. Found an answer elsewhere involving regedit that I applied before  also applying your answer.  A bit unsure of the root cause though suspect registry corruption as I found some irregularities in screenshot related registry keys in regedit and corrected them also before trying your answer. Neglected  to shut down between though, so a little uncertain if it was the wonky looking registry key, or your solution that fixed it. Don't like playing with the registry as a rule. Would suggest anyone else having this problem try your answer FIRST before considering tweaking with the registry.